# NSDateFormatter based on the time settings of iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have the `NSDateFormatter` for displaying time as `h:mm` to display time as 7:50 PM for example.

It works fine for phones with time showing as `5:55 PM` etc. but there are phones in different countries with time showing on the Status Bar as 05:55 PM and with that setting the `NSDateTimeFormatter` with `h:mm` seem to return (null).

Are there any workarounds or is there a best way to handle these situations? I was thinking off to check for nil and then retry `NSDateFormatter` with `hh:mm` but that sounds ugly to me. I wanted to make sure I do it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work by converting every date and time using the "en_US_POSIX" locale. I know, it's not truly what I want but it works across different region and time formats. I still have to figure out how to express these dates and times purely based on the user's region and time formats. Maybe, for another day.

Answer (score 0):

```
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

For language German and region format Germany, it logs `01:46`, while for English and United States it logs `1:46 AM`. And I checked: it will print `13:52` and `1:52 PM` correctly for times after noon.

Comment: I see, do you think having [NSLocale currentLocale] will automatically substitute the format for me? I don't want to hardcode a certain format (I've burnt the bridge already ;-) if you know what I mean.

Comment: I do not think so — I know it.

Comment: It's kind of hard to test as well. Do you know how to set the time to hh:mm (05:55 PM, for example) on our Status Bar so I can test and try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I tried, but couldn't get it to 05:55 PM. It's kind of weird to ask being in this for a while now, hey, but no one knows everything, right? ;-) If you find out please let me know.